# SQL Union/Join Conundrum

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, union

I cannot find anything that seems to fit the bill.  That may be because I don't know exactly what I am looking for, but hopefully you all can help.

I have 2 tables.  In Table1, I have three columns that I want to merge into a single column for this query.  Each is based on a different criteria.  I am currently accomplishing this via a Union (I just want unique).  Basically:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2 as Union_Data FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria1 = XXX
UNION
SELECT Column1, Column3 FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria2 = xxx
UNION
SELECT Column1, Column4 FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria3 = xxx
```

I want to then join to a second table where Union_Data = Table2.Column1 and select Table2.Column2.
The output would essential be three columns.  Table1.Column1, Union_Data, Table2.Column2  I can get the first two columns via the union, but the third column (which exists only in the second table and is joined based on the Union_Data column) escapes me.

Thanks to anyone who can help me out.

Comment: Your problem would be much easier to understand if you edited the question and provided sample data along with desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

```
SELECT u.Column1, Union_Data, Table2.Column2
FROM 
  (
    SELECT Column1, Column2 as Union_Data FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria1 = XXX
    UNION
    SELECT Column1, Column3 FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria2 = xxx
    UNION
    SELECT Column1, Column4 FROM Table1 WHERE Criteria3 = xxx
  ) u 
     INNER JOIN 
    Table2 ON 
        u.Union_Data = Table2.Column1
```